# Ofstream doesn't work well?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

In this code, fout is an ofstream object, It supposes to write to a file called `output.txt`. For a reason `output.txt` always empty!. I would ask about the mistake I did in the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>//to pause console screen
using namespace std;

double Volume(double);

int main() {
    ifstream fin; //read object
    ofstream fout;// writing object
    double Radius;
    fin.open("input.txt");
    fout.open("output.txt");
    if(!fin){
        cout<<"There a problem, input.txt can not be reached"<<endl;
    }
    else{
fin>>Radius;
fout<<Volume(Radius);
cout<<"Done! check output.txt file to see the sphare volume"<<endl;
    }

    getchar();//to pause console screen
return 0;
}

double Volume(double r){

double vol;
vol= (4.0/3.0)*3.14*r*r*r;
return vol;
}
```

Comment: Buffering. Flush it by calling `fout.flush ()` before calling `getchar ()` and you are good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"output.txt always empty"

I suspect that you are not allowing `fout` to flush its output. Do either of these statements apply to you?

- You check the contents of "output.txt" after the `getchar()` is
  invoked, but before the program ends?
- You end the program with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

If so, you have not allowed the data to be written to `fout`. You can solve this problem by avoiding those two conditions, or doing one of these:

- Add `fout << endl` after you write your data, or
- Add `fout << flush` after you write your data, or
- Add `fout.close()` after you write your data.

Comment: Looks good. I was too lazy to write it, but I added a fancy Ctrl+C buttons for you :) +1

Answer (score 3):

You have to flush the stream, call `fout.flush()` after you are done outputting, all you are doing is building a buffer that has yet to be written to the file. `flush` actually puts the buffer into the file.

Comment: File streams are automatically flushed when they are closed, including when they are implicitly closed at destruction.

Comment: @Rob: Right. But he is calling `getchar ()` which blocks the program until some terminal input. So buffer is stay unflushed while he is checking the file.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Agreed, see my answer. The point is that "never written to the file" is misleading.

Comment: @Rob True, I should have clarified the "never" statement. hopefully the edit is more agreeable

Answer (score 1):

In addition to calling `fout.flush()` you could change:

```
fout<<Volume(Radius);
```

to

```
fout<<Volume(Radius) << std::endl; // Writes a newline and flushes.
```

or you can close the stream `fout.close()` if it is no longer required.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `ofstream::close()`. I think it should always be called when the file no longer needs to be open. The file gets closed regardless, but doing it explicitly is better as it documents your intent.